# git multiple accounts and repository problems

Tags: git, visual-studio, github, ssh, version-control

I want to use git with Visual Studio project. I already had a personal account which worked fine. Now my employer gave me a new account and visual studio is still trying to push to my personal account and gives me error on publish and syncs.

So i followed this tutorial:https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-work-with-github-and-multiple-accounts--net-22574

- created new ssh key
- created an identity to it
- added that ssh key to my github account
- added identity to ssh config

Now some of the things i am unclear about

i have created 2 origins + the default one which are
origin (default)
myorigin (not used)
georigin (path:git@github-ge:ge/geweb)

when i type
    $ git config --global -l
it gives me my correct(employer's) user.name and user.email

**geweb** is the name of my new repository
the url of my repository is:**https://github.com/ge/geweb.git**

when i try pushing to georigin it says **repository not found**
when i try pushing to origin it says
**error: src refspec master does not match any.**

also, no where have i mentioned my second git account's username and password

also, i have 2 emails in my git account user.email in config is not the primary one. could that be the reason?

i am quiet confused at how it works end-to-end.

After failing to push i tried to unbind the project from source and deleted .git files from my project folder
but team explorer is still showing unsynced commits and changes

the output of
git remote -v is:

- myorigin        git@github-ge:ge:getWeb.git (fetch)
- myorigin        git@github-ge:ge:geWeb.git (push)

Comment: There are too many things that might be causing the problem. Consider narrowing and specifying your question.

Comment: as a starting point : what is origin and what does git@github-ge represent in the path git@github-ge:ge/geweb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turned out that i had multiple problems with setting up my account.

1. it was picking the wrong origin which was identified by Shaun and Marina

So, i removed the wrong one and added the correct one (georign)

2. I had added a readme file to the default repository it was giving me error:
   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

so i tried a pull before pushing and it turned out i had to --allow-unrelated-histories

```
git pull georigin master --allow-unrelated-histories
```

and then

```
git push georigin master
```

Thats it!!! (phew)

Answer (score 2):

Assume your private account and repo is https://github.com/my/repo.git and the second account and repo you want to use is :https://github.com/ge/geweb.git. The whole steps as below:

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "second account email address"`
2. Rename files for id_rsa, such as `Enter file in which to save the key (/c/Users /.ssh/id_rsa): /c/Users /.ssh/id_rsa_ge`
3. In the directory `c:\Users \.ssh` copy the content of `id-rsa_ge.pub` to the second github account as SSH key.
4. `touch /c/Users /.ssh/config`
5. modify the config content as below:

`Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

`Host github-ge
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_ge`

6. clone your private repo by `git clone https://github.com/my/repo.git`
7. `git remote add geweb git@github-ge:ge/geweb.git`
8. `git push geweb master` or `git push geweb master -f`

Comment: Dear i have already done all these steps and on git push geweb master i am  getting a repository not found error!! This was my question in the first place

Comment: It should be `git@github-ge:ge/geWeb.git` instead of `git@github-ge:ge:geWeb.git`.

Comment: Marina how do i edit the above?i want to use georigin that i defined previously as git@github-ge:ge/geWeb.git

Comment: You can delete the wrong url by `git remote rm myorigin` and `git remote add georigin git@github-ge:ge/geWeb.git`. If you added a remote georigin before, you should also remove it by `git remote rm georigin`.

Comment: Thanks Marina the first part is sorted here! Now when i try to commit it shows me a list of irrelevant files and then says: "nothing added to commit but untracked files present". Does that mean i need to reconfigure my local repository? How?

Comment: Did the untrack files are which you added just now before commit? If yes, you should use `git add filename` or `git add .` and then commit the changes.

Comment: No those are just irrelevant files (present in my c:/my documents) :S i cannot add files one by one coz its a big .sln with many projects

Comment: If you want all of them are version controlled by git, you can use `git add .` to add all files at once.

Comment: Thanks Marina lemme try that out!

Comment: dah life is still not easy on me! Now it says: "Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.xx.xx' to the list of known hosts.
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/spadmin/.ssh/id_rsa_ge':
To github-ge:/ge/geWeb
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github-ge:/ge/geWeb'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing"

Comment: What were you doing when it showed the message? And you added remote `git@github-ge:/ge/geWeb`? It should `git@github-ge:ge/geWeb`, one more `/` in configuration.

Comment: i removed the georigin, created new one with path git@github-ge:ge/geWeb.git then did "git pull georigin" it still gave me the same error. after this i did "git push georigin master" it gave me the same error "To github-gradexpert:Gradexpert/GradexpertWeb
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github-gradexpert:Gradexpert/GradexpertWeb'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e..."

Comment: Please note This is my actual project folder. My local git repo is in c:/Users/spadmin/git

Comment: What's the output of `git remote -v` now?

Comment: georigin        git@github-ge:ge/geWeb (fetch)                                         georigin        git@github-ge:ge/geWeb (push)

Comment: How did you config the `github-gradexpert:Gradexpert/GradexpertWeb`? Why it hint something relate gradexpert when `git push georigin master`?

Comment: consider gradexpert as ge (i was replacing all gradexpert with ge before posting a comment for privacy)

Comment: If gradexpert is your private repo, and ge is the second repo you want to use. Just use gradexpert as the way you used before. You can `git clone https://github.com/your_private/repo.git`, `git pull origin`, `git push origin`. The prerequisite is you were not over write `.ssh/id_rsa` and `.ssh/id_rsa_ge` (steps in my answer).

Comment: well i am copying the url from my repo and it says "Cloning into 'GradexpertWeb'...
remote: Repository not found."

Comment: If you use http protocol you can clone successfully. If you ssh protocol and failed to clone, you should check your id_rsa and if you have added a ssh key on github.

Comment: i cannot find my id_rsa since the start (maybe its in another location) but i have successfully added id_rsa_ge and added the same to ge repository on github too.

Comment: This is a more elaborate error when i try to pull "From github-ge:ge/geWeb
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
" Also when i created repository i added the readme file

Comment: ok finally :D this is alll sorted out! Thanks MArina for your continuous support. I am posting an answer

Answer (score 1):

> what is origin and what does git@github-ge represent in the path git@github-ge:ge/geweb

`origin` is an arbitrary name given to a remote repository. It often represents the repository from which the local repository cloned itself.

For instance, if you ran `git clone git@github.com:jquery/jquery.git`, then you would end up with `origin` pointing at that cloned URI.

The `git@github-ge` part of your URI represents a user at a server (`user@server`). You can [read about Git's protocols including the SSH protocol here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

For most people, that part of the URI means that Git is using SSH instead of HTTPS to communicate with the remote. Practically speaking, SSH requires an SSH key and running SSH agent, whereas HTTPS requires a username/password.

Comment: ok so origin is remote repo at github! and both my georigin and origin point to the same one. Only that origin is http based and georigin is ssh based. Also, git@github-ge is added to my ssh config file only do i need to mention it somewhere else too? so now my question is when i try pushing to georigin it says "repository not found" note there is no repositoy name with this message just blank spaces. thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Please post in your question the output of `git remote -v` and then ping me back here.

Comment: Hi Shaun, i have posted the output the origin showing in not georigin but myorigin which i am not using

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve this by removing the Host * from my file, check `~/.ssh/config` that doesn't work

```
Host *
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com-workaccount
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github.com-workaccount
```

Now, check the one that works just fine

```
Host github.com
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  HostName github.com
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Host github.com-workaccount
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_github.com-workaccount
```

Thanks